# Script to hide sheets from specific users?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet which I have shared with my team.
Each tab contains sensitive info of specific team member, which I do not want the other team members to see.

Cell C3 of all tabs contains that team-member's respective email ID.

Is there any way I can write a script such that when they login with that ID, the script will note the ID and hide all the other sheets and show them only their tab?

The tab is named with their names, which I also mentioned in C2 of every tab.

I am also sharing a sample file for your review here.

[Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fwp77xMRfwV3eq_uYttv4n_R1shQbEBj3DPTUegf_gw/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Every user sees the same view of the spreadsheet. You can write a script to hide sheets when a user opens the spreadsheet, but those sheets will also be hidden for other users who happen to have the spreadsheet open at the same time. And vice versa — any sheets that are unhidden will be visible to all users.

Besides, hiding sheets is not a reliable way to make sensitive information inaccessible. To do this properly with a Google Sheets backend, you will need a [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). See the [Web App Demo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/153204/embed-an-interactive-calculator-in-my-website-using-google-sheets) answer for more information and sample code.